# Multipart response in Sinatra

Tags: file-io, sinatra

I'm building a document service on sinatra. In the response, I want to send the JSON data and an attachment. How can I do this in sinatra?

Comment: How about including your file byte string in your json? Or much simpler just use 2 request on for your json file and one for your attachment, or what is the reason that you would merge these?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. I have changed the API design to handle these in 2 different calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to provide just two routes.

Something like this:

```
get "/json" do
    return json
end

get "/file/:name" do |filename|
    send_file file.filePath, :filename => file.fileName, :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

And in your json respons you include the path to your file.